# The program is skipping the if in my if else statement PHP

Tags: php, html, if-statement

Here is my php code:

```
        <?php
            $amount = $_GET["startingAmount"];
            $whichWay = $_GET["whichWay"];
            $conversion = $_GET["conversion"];
            $step = $_GET["step"];
            if (is_numeric($conversion)) 
            {
                if ($whichWay === "1") 
                {
                    echo "<table>";
                        echo "<tr><th>USD</th><th>Canadian</th></tr>";
                        for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++) 
                        {                        
                            $outputValue = $amount * $conversion;
                            echo "<tr><td>$amount</td><td>$outputValue</td></tr>";
                            $amount = $amount+$step;
                        }
                    echo "</table>";
                } 
                else
                {
                    echo "<table>";
                        echo "<tr><th>Canadian</th><th>USD</th></tr>";
                        for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++) 
                        {                        
                            $outputValue = $amount * $conversion;
                            echo "<tr><td>$amount</td><td>$outputValue</td></tr>";
                            $amount = $amount+$step;
                        }
                    echo "</table>";
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                    echo "<p>You did not input a numeric value for both the amount you wanted to convert and for the conversion rate.<br>Please go back and do it again</p>";
            }
        ?>
```

Here is the html form that sends the information:

```
<body>
        <h1>USD/Canadian Money Conversion Site</h1>
        <div>
            <form method="get" action="output.php">            
                Starting Amount: 
                    <select name="startingAmount" size="1">
                        <option name="1">1</option>
                        <option name="10">10</option>
                        <option name="20">20</option>
                    </select><br> 
                Conversion type:
                    <select name="whichWay" size="1">
                        <option name="1">USD to Canadian</option>
                        <option name="2">Canadian to USD</option>
                    </select><br>  
                Conversion Rate: <input type="text" name="conversion" required><br>
                Step:
                    <select name="step" size="1">
                        <option name="1">1</option>
                        <option name="2">2</option>
                        <option name="3">3</option>
                        <option name="4">4</option>
                    </select><br> 
                <input type="submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
```

For some reason the php does not recognize the value of whichWay if the user selects USD to Canadian or vice versa and just runs the else statement.
Everything else works fine.  The program can run the else statement and the rest of the variables work fine.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `<option name="1">` to `<option value="1">` and do the same for all `<option` elements.

Answer (score 1):

You have "names" in the HTML code but not "values".

in the "select", in each option, instead of having "name='1'" you should have "value='1'", etc

Answer (score 1):

[Option elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) in HTML do not use a `name` attribute, they use a `value` attribute.

Your HTML should be changed to reflect this;

```
<form method="get" action="output.php">            
    Starting Amount: 
        <select name="startingAmount" size="1">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
        </select><br> 
    Conversion type:
        <select name="whichWay" size="1">
            <option value="1">USD to Canadian</option>
            <option value="2">Canadian to USD</option>
        </select><br>  
    Conversion Rate: <input type="text" name="conversion" required><br>
    Step:
        <select name="step" size="1">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
        </select><br> 
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Your PHP code can also majorly be improved, this is equivalent to your current code, but as you can see MUCH shorter and reduces duplicate code. This can also much more easily be expanded by just adding new types to the `$types` array.

```
<?php
    $amount = $_GET["startingAmount"];
    $whichWay = $_GET["whichWay"];
    $conversion = $_GET["conversion"];
    $step = $_GET["step"];

    $types = [
        ["USD", "Canadian"],
        ["Canadian", "USD"]
    ];

    if (is_numeric($conversion)) 
    {
        echo "<table>";

            $type = $types[$whichWay - 1];
            //$type will now == ["USD", "Canadian"] (if $whichWay is 1), so you can use array indexes to select the proper label

            echo "<tr><th>{$type[0]}</th><th>{$type[1]}</th></tr>";
            for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++) 
            {                        
                $outputValue = $amount * $conversion;
                echo "<tr><td>$amount</td><td>$outputValue</td></tr>";
                $amount = $amount+$step;
            }
        echo "</table>";
    } else {
        echo "<p>You did not input a numeric value for both the amount you wanted to convert and for the conversion rate.<br>Please go back and do it again</p>";
    }
?>
```